# How to add specific word randomly to targeted txt file using php?

Tags: php

I want to add words into a txt document into sentences from the selected list in a text document with php.
For example; lorem.txt is the text file like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at
>   vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent
>   luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

and list.txt is the wordlist like this:

> hello
>   stackoverflow
>   you are great

and final text will be like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor **hello** sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
>   sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet **stackoverflow**
>   dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
>   nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit **you are great** lobortis
>   nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure
>   dolor in **hello** hendrerit in vulputate velit esse **stackoverflow**
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at
>   vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent
>   luptatum zzril delenit augue duis **you are great** dolore te feugait
>   nulla facilisi.

Thank for help.

Comment: You should show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use `file_get_contents` to read the file
- `explode(" ", $content)` to split the contents of the file on a space so you get an array with words.
- then you can insert the new words in random places in that array using `array_splice`.

-

```
$loremfile = "lorem.txt";
$wordsfile = "list.txt";
$resultfile = "result.txt";

// check if $loremfile exists
if (!file_exists($loremfile)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Lorem file does not exists [" . realpath($loremfile) . "]");
}

// check if $wordsfile exists
if (!file_exists($wordsfile)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Words file does not exists [" . realpath($wordsfile) . "]");
}

// check if $resultfile exists
if (file_exists($resultfile)) {
    // check if we can overwrite the $resultfile
    if (!is_writable($resultfile)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Not enough permissions to overwrite result file [" . realpath($resultfile) . "]");
    }
} else {
    // check if we're allowed to create $resultfile
    if (!is_writable(dirname($resultfile))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Not enough permissions to create result file [" . realpath($resultfile) . "]");
    }
}

// read $loremfile and explode on spaces
$lorem = explode(" ", file_get_contents($loremfile));
// array_map(trim) the each word and array_filter to remove empty lines
$lorem = array_filter(array_map('trim', $lorem));

// read $wordsfile and explode on newlines
$words = explode("\n", file_get_contents($wordsfile));
// array_map(trim) the each word and array_filter to remove empty lines
$words = array_filter(array_map('trim', $words));

// print words (for debugging)
var_dump($words);

// loop over words
foreach ($words as $word) {
    // get a random spot in the $lorem array
    $randomIndex = array_rand($lorem);
    // insert the $word into the $randomIndex spot of $lorem
    array_splice($lorem, $randomIndex, 0, $word);
}

// print result (for debugging)
var_dump($lorem, implode(" ", $lorem));

// write result to $resultfile
file_put_contents($resultfile, implode(" ", $lorem));
```

Comment: when i try your code print the screen:
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: anyway, it probably can't find the file "list.txt", maybe put an absolute path there instead

Comment: i try but this time result was "array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "hello" [1]=> string(13) "stackoverflow" [2]=> string(13) "you are great" }"

Comment: I updated the example to be a bit better - it now checks if the files exists and it will write the result to "result.txt"